# How to add image base tool control to a drop-down list in ArcGIS 9.3.1

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, visual-studio

I have to retrograde an ESRI add-in application from ArcGIS 10.1 to ArcGIS 9.3.1.

My challenge is how in the drop down list can I add base tool control( will be shown as icons inside the drop down list : red and green icons )[image],

In ArcGIS 9.3.1 is easier to create a drop down list containing text:

[image]

By default a drop down list can't contain image , how can I overcome that?

Comment: After re-reading your question... I am curious as to how the dropdown in the first screenshot was implemented. Is that actually a dropdown (combobox) or a menu?

Comment: In VS 2010 add-in solution  right click on the solution and add ArcGIS Add-in component and then choose Tool Palette .At this stage you will get a tool palette that u can add tools on it or u can edit the esri add-in xml file  by adding <ToolPalette> <Items> <Tool....

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing out of visual studio try using Listview control instead of a listbox.  You can use the [ListViewItem.ImageKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imagekey.aspx).

Comment: Thanks this has resolved the challenge and I was even able to have icon and text label associated with the icon